# Next 13 and server side component caching with Apollo Client

Tags: apollo-client, next.js13

I am experimenting with Next 13 (coming from a straight React JS background) to understand how and if I should start using it. The biggest confusion I am having is around caching of server rendered components, specifically when said components are responsible for fetching data.

My first confusion is that when routing using the Next Link component, the Page (and any nested server components) are not re-requested from the server which, for any data fetching, seems problematic as the components will never refresh. How should this be handled in a way that will allow me to control when a server component should be re-requested from the server when navigating using Link?

Secondly, if I force a page to refresh I am still having issues with controlling the refetching of data within server components. I am using Apollo Client and following this guide on the Apollo site https://www.apollographql.com/blog/announcement/frontend/using-apollo-client-with-next-js-13-releasing-an-official-library-to-support-the-app-router/

```
import { getClient } from "@/lib/client";
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

interface TimeData {
    now: string
}

const serverDate = new Date().toString();

const query = gql`query Now {
    now(id: "1")
}`;

export default async function ServerSide() {
    
    const gqlData = await getClient().query<TimeData>({
        query,
        context: {
            fetchOptions: {
                next: { revalidate: 10 }
            }
        }
    });

    return (
        <div className="p-4 w-[45%] border-solid border-2 border-black rounded float-left mr-5 ml-5">
            <h1 className="font-bold">Server Side Rendered</h1>
            <div>API Time: {gqlData.data.now}</div> 
            <div>Server Time: {serverDate}</div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The above code (when hard refreshed) updates the date coming back from the graphQL request on every refresh (ignoring the 10 second re-fetch config), but doesn't update the serverDate.

Infact, if I remove the context property, the behavior remains the same, as it does if I add either of the following:

```
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";
export const revalidate = false;
```

My question then is how should we be using RSC in a way that allows us to control when they should be re-rendered (on route change) and when they should re-fetch their data (specifically via Apollo Client) when they are served. Ideally I would want a way to specify that server component X needs to be re-requested after x seconds at which point Id want any data it fetches to have similar cache invalidation, but from all the docs I've read this doesn't seem straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same exact wall. What I found is that the `fetchOptions` inside of `context` are not respected (or connected) to the front-end of the app. However, you may have noticed that `fetch` calls made from the Next server do, indeed, respect options such as `next: { revalidate: 10 }`.

This led me to a sustainable answer for my project, which was to *not* use Apollo Client in the traditional manner, as you have illustrated in your example. Instead, make your GraphQL call via `fetch`. Here's a simplified example.

**page.tsx**

```js
const getItems = async (itemId: string, query: DocumentNode) => {
  const variables = {
    // variables used by the query
  }

  const response = await fetch(GRAPHQL_URI, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ query: query.loc?.source.body, variables }),
    next: { revalidate: 30, tags: [`item-${itemId}`] },
  })

  return response.json()
}


export default async function Page({ params: { itemId } }: PropertyPageProps) {
  let promise: Promise<ApolloQueryResult<ItemQueryResult>>

  try {
    promise = getItems(itemId, ItemDocument)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
    throw err
  }

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<DefaultLoader />}>
      <SomeComponent promise={promise} />
    </Suspense>
  )
}
```

The key things to notice:

- the query was made via `fetch`
- tags: [`item-${itemId}`]

Now we can revalidate this tag from anywhere in our app, and the data cache will be purged for that request, and the consuming components rehydrated on the next visit. Next provides `revalidateTag` and `revalidatePath`, which must be run as a server action.

According to Next's [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/revalidateTag):

> revalidateTag allows you to purge cached data on-demand for a specific cache tag.

**actions.ts**

```js
'use server'

import { revalidatePath, revalidateTag } from 'next/cache'

export async function _revalidatePath(
  path: string,
  type: 'page' | 'layout' = 'page'
) {
  revalidatePath(path, type)
}

export async function _revalidateTag(path: string) {
  revalidateTag(path)
}
```

You can call this server action from somewhere in a client component, like in a click event.

```js
onClick={() => _revalidateTag(`item-${itemId}`)}
```

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I had also run into the same problem and managed to solve it. As Andy Hoffman correctly points out, the issue is not with Next.js revalidate. However, I don't think you need to avoid using Apollo client in your project for that reason; luckily you just need to initialize correctly your Apollo client, as stated in the documentation - see below.
Simply install this package @apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support and initialize the client not with new apolloClient but instead with these two Next.js experimental functions NextSSRInMemoryCache, NextSSRApolloClient:

```
// lib/client.js
import { HttpLink } from "@apollo/client";
import {
  NextSSRInMemoryCache,
  NextSSRApolloClient,
} from "@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support/ssr";
import { registerApolloClient } from "@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support/rsc";

export const { getClient } = registerApolloClient(() => {
  return new NextSSRApolloClient({
    cache: new NextSSRInMemoryCache(),
    link: new HttpLink({
      uri: "https://main--time-pav6zq.apollographos.net/graphql",
    }),
  });
});
```

hope that helps!